# Testing user-set variable for equality in ELisp

Tags: elisp

I am new to Emacs Lisp and changing some code in [mu4e-send-delay](https://github.com/bandresen/mu4e-send-delay/). I want to test whether the user set a variable to a value, e.g. in the scratch buffer:

```
(setq mu4e-sent-messages-behavior 'delete)
delete
```

These three tests return false:

```
(eq 'mu4e-sent-messages-behavior 'delete)
nil
(equal 'mu4e-sent-messages-behavior 'delete)
nil
(equal 'mu4e-sent-messages-behavior "delete")
nil
```

And this one returns true, but with the `member` function for lists:

```
(if (member mu4e-sent-messages-behavior '(delete)) t nil)
t
```

If the user keeps the setting at the default set in the code:

```
(defcustom mu4e-sent-messages-behavior 'sent
...
)
```

then `member` also fails:

```
(when (member mu4e-sent-messages-behavior '(sent)) t nil)
nil
```

What is wrong with my tests, and how can I test for the value of a variable set by the user?

Comment: The quote means that you are testing whether the *symbol* `mu4e-sent-messages-behavior` is the same thing as the symbol `delete` (or the string `"delete"`), and of course it isn't -- they are different symbols (or a symbol and a string).  You want be testing the variable's *value*, not the variable's symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't quote the variable name when passing it to `eq`:

```
(eq mu4e-sent-messages-behavior 'delete)
```

---

The problem with this piece of code:

```
(when (member mu4e-sent-messages-behavior '(sent)) t nil)
```

is that `when` will either return `nil` (if the condition is false) or the *last* value of the body (if the condition is true), which in this case is `nil` - so this piece of code will always return `nil`.  Use `if` instead of `when`, and you should see it returning `t`.